# windows 10 after sleep or wake up all browser stops working but software internet works even cmd ping works

Tags: windows, windows-10

**windows 10 version 21h2 os build 19044.1706** internet stops working on all browsers after waking up from sleep or lock screen.

all software installed that requires internet works. games/steam/software all works great.
cmd ping works with no issue.

I have a top-range pc AMD 5950x just been having this issue for some time no virus was clean installed from 4months back and I don't know what can be the cause.

video link below youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vrzsVf3NCg

***oh and a reboot gets it all working but I need to fix it so I don't need to reboot all again since I could be working on something and closing it and rebooting it all again can be a headache***

Comment: Update your BIOS and Power Drivers.  Run the manufacturer's driver update app. Reinstall Chrome, other installable browsers and Repair Edge.  Do a final restart and test.

Comment: every restart works always just does this when it sleeps or lock screen. all drivers are up to date even bios

Comment: Perhaps at this point do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link. Start with the option to Keep Everything and see if that works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found this same issue on my PC was solved by un-installing and re-installing my antivirus (Bitdefender in my case).  Various antivirus vendors add root certificates and other software to web browsers to protect you from vulnerabilities and these can sometimes cause this issue when they are not updated correctly over time.  A re-install can fix this.